# I want to read the values from one textarea and pass the same values to another textarea in django?

Tags: python, django

*I want to user input column-wise value in textarea and then clicking on a button/running the code (button click code not done yet) the value in textarea will pass to another textarea. I sucessufully did with textbox, but it is not working for text area. Please guide me here (I want to do this in Django).*

```
<pre>
**Index.html code:**


{% block content %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<form action="one" method = "post">
{%csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name ="text"><br>
<input type="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
</pre>

<pre>**Views.py code:**


from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
import cgi,cgitb

# Create your views here.

def index(request):  
    
        
    return render(request,"index.html")

def one(request):
       
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    user = form.getvalue("text")           
            
    return render(request,"one.html",{"user":user})

</pre>

<pre>**One.html**

{% block content %}
<Html>
<body>
{%csrf_token %}

<input type = "text" value = {{user}}>

<h2>{{user}}</h2>
<h2>{{user}}</h2>
</body>
</Html>
{% endblock %}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do that without reloading page then it is not django question. you can do it with javascript or jQuery.
put this into html page

```
<textarea id="text_area1"></textarea>
<textarea id="text_area2"></textarea>
<script language="Javascript">
function copyTextArea() {
    document.getElementById("text_area2").value = document.getElementById("text_area1").value;
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="copy" onclick="copyTextArea()">
```

Comment: Post receiving the input from one textarea and I want to perform a certain operations(like add a comma in the string) and then want to display in the second textarea, in this case, do I need to code in Django or jQuery will do?

Comment: if you need just update message, that user put into first TextArea you don't need to post it to server you can use Javascript to perform all operation, and then post final message. Send to server only if you want to save this unedited data to database, or you have some complex manipulations, which can be done only by server side

Comment: Thank you Andrey, it helps! :-)